Spring boot/Spring WebClient - The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response
from a Spring Boot 3.3.3 microservice - JDK 22, I am trying to contact a Spring Boot 3.1.6 microservice - JDK 18, which in turn makes asynchronous calls to a third microservice. The connection between the first microservice and the second one works correctly, but when the second microservice tries to asynchronously contact the third, I receive the error: "The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response."
Below is the first call (non-asynchronous) to the second microservice:
       return mercurioDocumentApiClient.getWebClient().post()
                .uri(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(mercurioDocumentApiClient.getBasePath())
                        .path("/documents/upload")
                        .build()
                        .toUri()
                )
                .header("idSession", idSession)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartBodyBuilder.build()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Document.class)
                .flatMap(document -> {
                    AllegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData = new AllegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData();
                    allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData.setIdDocumento(BigDecimal.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(document.getId())));
                    allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData.setRiferimentoDoc(null);
                    allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData.setDocumentIdClient(document.getDocumentCode());
                    allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData.setContentId(Long.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(document.getContentCode())));
                    return Mono.just(allegaDocumentoDocumentaleOutputData);
                })
                .block();

The other calls originating from the second microservice:
        return filePartMono.flatMap(filePart -> {
            // Check document id client
            if (Objects.isNull(documentIdClientFormFieldPart) || StringUtils.isEmpty(documentIdClientFormFieldPart.value())) {
                return webClient.flatMap(client -> {
                    DocumentCreateForm documentCreateForm = new DocumentCreateForm();
                    documentCreateForm.setTitle(filePart.filename());
                    documentCreateForm.path(String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getYear()));

                    // Create new document
                    return client
                            .post()
                            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("mercurio-contents", "api", "v1", "documents", mercurioProperties.getDomainCode(), mercurioProperties.getApplicationCode(), mercurioProperties.getContextCode(), "create").build())
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(documentCreateForm))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(DocumentResponse.class)
                            .flatMap(documentResponse -> {
                                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(documentResponse.getSummary().getError())) {
                                    return Mono.error(() -> new IllegalStateException(Arrays.toString(ListUtils.emptyIfNull(documentResponse.getSummary().getMessages()).toArray())));
                                }

                                log.info("Document created {}", Objects.requireNonNull(documentResponse.getPayload()).getDocumentIdClient());

                                return uploadFile(filePart.content(), filePart.filename(), pages, documentResponse.getPayload().getDocumentIdClient(), Optional.ofNullable(acquisitionStatusFormFieldPart).map(FormFieldPart::value).orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY), principal.getName());
                            });
                });



This call triggers the error
return client
                            .post()
                            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("mercurio-contents", "api", "v1", "documents", mercurioProperties.getDomainCode(), mercurioProperties.getApplicationCode(), mercurioProperties.getContextCode(), "create").build())
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(documentCreateForm))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(DocumentResponse.class)
                            .flatMap(documentResponse -> {
                                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(documentResponse.getSummary().getError())) {
                                    return Mono.error(() -> new IllegalStateException(Arrays.toString(ListUtils.emptyIfNull(documentResponse.getSummary().getMessages()).toArray())));
                                }

                                log.info("Document created {}", Objects.requireNonNull(documentResponse.getPayload()).getDocumentIdClient());

                                return uploadFile(filePart.content(), filePart.filename(), pages, documentResponse.getPayload().getDocumentIdClient(), Optional.ofNullable(acquisitionStatusFormFieldPart).map(FormFieldPart::value).orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY), principal.getName());
                            });




If you just curl the second service, does it work as expected? And when you curl the third one, i.e., separately, does it work?

The curl on the third microservice works correctly, on the second one it doesn’t.The error message is the one reported.”I would add that the first microservice was initially running on Spring Boot 2.7.4 / JDK18, and everything was working fine. The problem started after it was migrated to 3.3.3

Okay. If you look at the connection between this two services (using wireshark, tcpdump, whatever), what happens?
